# Why I get NullPointerException?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I keep getting NullPointerException in the following code.
The exception appears at this line `System.out.println(myHeros.toString());`

public class test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hero A = new Hero("Archer");
    Hero B = new Hero("Bacca");
    Hero C = new Hero("Chester");
    Hero D = new Hero("Teemo");
    Hero E = new Hero("Garen");

    MyStack myHeros = new MyStack(10);

    System.out.println(!(A instanceof Hero)); // Output: false;

    boolean debug = true;
    try {

        myHeros.push(A);
        if(debug) {
            System.out.println("lalala");
        }
    }
    catch(notAHeroException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(myHeros.toString());   //This is the line that throws nullPointerException;

    System.out.println(myHeros.getTop()); //(Debug) Output: 1, the Hero was actually pushed into myHeroStack;           
}
```

}

This is the class containing the toString method. I really cannot see where possibly can cause a NullPointerException.

```
public class MyStack implements Stack{

public Hero[] myHeroStack; //instance field; can be from this class to the whole world;
int top;                   //The combination of these instance fields represent all you know about your object and all you can use about your object;

public MyStack() {
    myHeroStack = new Hero[5];
    top = 0;

}

public MyStack(int numOfHero) {
    myHeroStack = new Hero[numOfHero];  
    top = 0;
}

@Override
public void push(Hero h) throws notAHeroException{
    //check the input;
    boolean checkType = !(h instanceof Hero);
    if (checkType) {        //if (!(h instanceof Hero))
        throw new notAHeroException("Check again what did you add?!");
    }

    else {
        myHeroStack[top] = h;
        top = top + 1;
    }

}

@Override
public void pull(Hero g) throws emptyStackException { //check whether the element you want to throw actually exist;
    //check whether the element exist
    if(myHeroStack[top - 1] == null) {
        throw new emptyStackException("You do have this hero in you stack!");

    }
    else {
        Hero heroToPull = myHeroStack[top - 1];
        System.out.println(heroToPull.getName());
        myHeroStack[top - 1] = null;
        top = top -1;

    }

}

@Override
public void peek(Hero p) {
    System.out.println(p.getName());
}

public int getTop() {
    return top;
}

public String toString() {
    //check whether the stack is null
    if(top == 0) {
        return ("You hero stack is empty");
    }
    else {
        String AllMyHero = "";
        for(Hero hero: myHeroStack) {           
            AllMyHero = AllMyHero + "All my hero is " + hero.getName()+ "%n"; //hero is null point
        }
        return AllMyHero;
    }


}
```

}

This is the Hero class, which is quite simple.

```
public class Hero {

    private String name;

    public Hero(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Thank you for all who takes a look at this question!

Comment: You have an array of uninitialized `Hero`s.

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing `myHeroStack` by doing `myHeroStack = new Hero[5];` which basically means to prepare 5 places for 5 `Hero` objects. This will be the look of your stack at initialization.

myHeroStack :

```
null 
null
null
null
null
```

Then in your main you added `Hero A = new Hero("Archer");` by doing this `myHeros.push(A);` thus the look of your stack will be.

myHeroStack :

```
A (The Hero you added)
null
null
null
null
```

Now in your print method you used `for(Hero hero: myHeroStack) {` which basically means to iterate each element of your stack. Thus when the second iteration occurs the `hero` in your loop will be null. That is why NullPointerException occurs.

You should update your print method to include a checking for null values. Refer to the code below.

```
public String toString() {
    //check whether the stack is null
    if(top == 0) {
        return ("You hero stack is empty");
    }
    else {
        String AllMyHero = "";
        for(Hero hero: myHeroStack) {  
            if (hero != null) {
                AllMyHero = AllMyHero + "All my hero is " + hero.getName()+ "%n"; //hero is null point
            }         
        }    
    }
        return AllMyHero;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the for loop in your toString() method to the code below so it won't print the null values in your array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
    // ...
}
```